# Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I built react project with webpack and babel.

It worked well.

But, today I got some error below.

```
ERROR in ./index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL] /home/rpf5573/react-discovery-v2/src/admin/admin-client/index.js: Invalid Option: corejs is not a valid top-level option.
        Maybe you meant to use 'targets'? (While processing: "/home/rpf5573/react-discovery-v2/src/admin/admin-client/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")
    at validateTopLevelOptions (/home/rpf5573/react-discovery-v2/src/admin/admin-client/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/normalize-options.js:49:13)
    at normalizeOptions (/home/rpf5573/react-discovery-v2/src/admin/admin-client/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/normalize-options.js:160:3)
    at _default (/home/rpf5573/react-discovery-v2/src/admin/admin-client/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:168:37)
  ....
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

And this is my `admin-client/.babelrc`

```
module.exports = {
  compact: true,
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        modules: false,
        targets: {
          browsers: ["since 2015"]
        },
        useBuiltIns: "usage",
        corejs: "2"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

What did I wrong ?

What should I do ?

Comment: Tried deleting node_modules?

Comment: @DennisVash nope, I just deleted `corejs: "2"` line from .babelrc. And now works well.

Comment: Also deleting your npm or yarn lock file and regenerating can help.

Comment: Not sure if that could be the case but for sure core3 goes in conflict with core2, could be that in your case some package is already looking for core3 https://www.thebasement.be/updating-to-babel-7.4/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Maybe you had some major version change recently?

In my case, that was the cause. And the **solution** was:

- Completely remove `node-modules` folder from the project
- Remove `package-lock.json` file from the project root folder
- Perform a `npm i` to recreate everything

Answer (score 3):

[image: I experienced the same challenge]

As an alternative to entirely deleting `node-modules` as suggested by @SysDragon. I looked deeper into why the complaint was specific to `corejs`. And i found a great remedy [here](https://github.com/fable-compiler/webpack-config-template/issues/12#issuecomment-490862309).

In summary, these were the steps taken:

- Install the latest version of [core-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) (or atleast version-3).
  Whatever you are building "might" be making use of latest JavaScript functionality. For my case, i was working with `react-16.9.0` and `mdbreact-4.19.0`.

> Note: Core-js is a Modular standard library for JavaScript. Includes polyfills for ECMAScript up to 2019: promises, symbols, collections, iterators, typed arrays and many other features.

- Then, you need to update your transpiler, `babel` and it's "relatives".
  This block snippet helped accomplish that: `yarn upgrade @babel/core @babel/plugin-transform-runtime @babel/polyfill @babel/preset-env @babel/runtime babel-loader --dev`.

> The `--dev` part is just to save them as devDependencies (if using yarn) (for npm, use `--save-dev`), which i advocate for especially if this is team project.

Comment: I just needed to install core-js. Thank you very much! o/

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the subdirectory I was working on was part of a larger Yarn workspace in the root of the repository and removing that subdirectory from the workspace and reinstalling `node_modules` within the subdirectory fixed the issue.

This issue is most likely caused by dependency mismatches.